# Quiero que siga dividiendo hasta que "a" y "b" ya no sean divisibles entre 2

Tags: c#

Quiero que siga dividiendo hasta que `a` y `b` ya no sean divisibles entre 2 y que después lo imprima en forma de fracción, pensé en hacerlo con un `do while` pero me sigue repitiendo y no para de repetir, aun cuando le estoy diciendo que deje de repetir cunado ya no sean divisibles.

```
double a;
double b;
double e;
double f;
Console.WriteLine("ingrese un numero");
a = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("ingrese otro numero");
b = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0)
{
    do
    {
        e = a / 2;
        f = b / 2;
    } while (!(e % 2 != 0 && b % 2 != 0));
}
else
{
    e = a;
    f = b;
}

Console.WriteLine(e + "/" + f);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: El problema es que a y b no son enteros.. entonces la division por dos siempre te va a dar un valor... ademas tu clausula en el while esta mal.. estas usando b en lugar de f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo unico que necesitas es utilizar un while con la condicion que tienes en el primer if que utilizas, o sea:

```
while(a%2==0 && b%2==0){
        a/=2;
        b/=2;
    }
```

Si la condicion no se cumple directamente imprimira "a" y "b" como los diste en la entrada de tu programa, si la condicion se cumple entrara en el ciclo y ejecutara lo que haya dentro de el y dejara de ejecutarse cuando la condicion ya no se cumpla y directamente pasara a la impresion en pantalla.

Comment: Ojo porque si no los pasa a enteros esa condicion no se va a cumplir nunca